# Security concerns using "SupportingFeeOnTransferTokens" on Uniswap/Pancakeswap functions

Tags: erc-20, tokens, uniswap, pancakeswap, swaps

I know that the difference between these kind of functions is that when supporting fees you are accepting that you are going to receive less tokens than expected. I have seen that both functions works indistinctly.

I'm developing an Smart Contract that must be able o trade any kind of token, and the approach seems to be the "SupportingFeeOnTransferTokens" option to work 100% of the times.

Does this approach have any kind of potential risk?

swapExactETHForTokens vs swapExactETHForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens

swapExactTokensForETH vs swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens

Comment: I'm still looking for this answer bro! did you figure out the differences? if yes, please update your post here.